In TypeScript, why "extends keyof" is used to declare generic type parameters with constraints instead of using "in keyof"?
typescriptlang.org, in its article about Generics, explains 2 uses of the keyword "extends" when declaring type parameters.

In Generic Constraints.

interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}
 
function loggingIdentity<Type extends Lengthwise>(arg: Type): Type {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}


When declaring a type parameter that is constrained by another type parameter.

function getProperty<Type, Key extends keyof Type>(obj: Type, key: Key) {
  return obj[key];
}
 
let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
 
getProperty(x, "a");

getProperty(x, "m");
// Error: Argument of type '"m"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b" | "c" | "d"'.

It makes sense to use the "extends" keyword when constraining a generic type so that it should have the properties and methods of the extended type. (See the 1st use above). This also matches the use of the "extends" keyword in inheritance in OOP.
But why is the "extends" keyword used in the 2nd instance above to constrain the generic type parameter "Key" so it should be a property of the type parameter "Type"? Why not use the keyword "in" as "in keyof Type", which makes more sense?
Thank you in advance for your answers and comments!
Note:
I know that "in keyof" is used when declaring mapped types as below.
type Optional<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K];
};

My question is why not use the same when constraining a generic type parameter when it should be a property of another type parameter?

"But why is the "extends" keyword used in the 2nd instance above to constrain the generic type parameter "Key" so it should be a property of the type parameter "Type"? Why not use the keyword "in" as "in keyof Type", which makes more sense?" because that would be a syntax error? https://tsplay.dev/m0D5Dm

It is truly extends and not in, assuming that by extends you mean "any subtype of" and by in you mean "a single member of".  (Of course you might have different interpretations of those keywords, but then this becomes an opinion question.)
For a mapped type, P in K means that P will be a single union member of K.
But that is not required for a generic constraint. P extends K means that P can be any subtype of K, which is not limited to a single union member. In your example you can write this:
getProperty(x, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "d");
/* function getProperty<{
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
    d: number;
}, "a" | "d"> */

Here Key is inferred as the union "a" | "d".  The type "a" | "d" is not "in" "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" according to the definition of in above. It's just a subtype.  Key can be any subtype of "a" | "b" | "c" | "d", including the full union, or "a" | "d", or never, or exotic things like "b" & {oops: true}. It is quite likely that when you call getProperty() the type Key will be inferred as an individual key, but it is not required, and one can always manually specify something else.
Note that it would be really helpful if TypeScript did have a concept of "this type parameter must be a single member of this union", and there is a longstanding feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#27808 for that. This would let you narrow the type parameter inside a generic function, which currently isn't possible (and leads to a related feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#33014):
interface Foo {
    a: string,
    b: number
}
function foo<K extends "a" | "b">(k: K): Foo[K] {
    if (k === "a")
        return "abc"; // error! k is "a" but K might be "a" | "b"
    else
        return 123; // error! k is "b" but K might be "a" | "b"
}

The feature request asks for extends oneof or extends_oneof. Possibly if it ever gets implemented it could use in instead (the feature request is about the functionality, not the syntax, and so while it's tempting to bikeshed and say "this should be in", it's sort of off-topic). But for now this is simply not part of the language. There's only one kind of generic constraint in TypeScript, and it means "any subtype", so we use extends and not in.
Playground link to code

The type "a" is a subtype of the type "a" | "b" | "c" | "d".
Languages that use the keyword extends for class inheritance do that because an inheriting class is a subtype of the inherited class.
keyof is an operator that transforms one type into another, it could easily be Key extends TypeKeys in that position.
